# Retrieving 'to' and 'from' addresses in transaction directly from blockchain

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain

I'm trying to get a list of addresses that have made transactions with a given bitcoin address for a project that examines how people use bitcoin for non-nefarious purposes. I've got a lot of addresses so a web based blockchain explorer like `blockchain.info` isn't practical.

I've downloaded the blockchain and used [bitcoin-abe](https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe) to dump it into a sqlite database.  However I'm not finding addresses anywhere.  Are the actual addresses called something different in the blockchain?

Answer (score 2):

The spending conditions, i.e., who is able to spend a given output, are encoded as scripts in the [output](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#transactions). What is commonly referred to as a Bitcoin address is little more than a default script format (either pay-to-pubkey or [pay-to-pubkey-hash](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#p2pkh-script-validation)) which require a signature from a private key matching the pubkey in the script. For example P2PKH scripts look like this:

```
OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <PubkeyHash> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG
```

This checks that the pubkey on the stack matches the hash, and then checks that the signature and pubkey are valid for the transaction.

ABE stores the output scripts, but appears not to create an index for the addresses. So you probably want to convert the addresses that you're looking for into the script version (see the [wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses) for details on how to extract the pubkey hash or pubkey from the address). Once you have the pubkey hash or pubkey you construct a binary script similar to this (hexencoded):

```
76a914<pubkey-hash>88ac
```

You should then be able to search for these in the database ABE gives you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a cron job using the BTC address of the user and check whether the transaction is made or not.

https://www.blockchain.com/explorer

Ex. https://github.com/bitpay/insight